# Calling `removeFromSuperView` for a view with no parent

Tags: ios, uiview

Is it advisable to call `someView.removeFromSuperView()` without checking for its parentView?

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
 super.prepareForReuse()
 someLabel.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I'm calling `removeFromSuperView` on a `lazy var label` inside `prepareForReuse()` in a collectionViewCell. The cell still holds an instance and it can add back when needed

Comment: It is safe to call `removeFromSuperView()` without checking its parentView